# How to retrieve Instagram home news feed for apps?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I am currently attempting to retrieve the news feed from my Instagram home feed to include into an app. Is there any way to use their API to get this info?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any public api that you can register and send requests to, but there are some reverse-engineered solutions.

Here's a library for php that claims to cover almost all features:

https://github.com/mgp25/Instagram-API